# Magento 2.3 get current local time in phtml

Tags: magento2.3, date, timezone

I want to load the current local time in a custom phtml file, that I want to load in my CMS Page.

I currently have the following code but that loads the GMC time, not my local time.

How can I change this?

CODE:

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
$date = $objDate->gmtDate();
$ndate = date('H:i', strtotime($date));
?>
<?php echo $ndate;?>
```

Comment: Is your location and server location one time zone?

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko Yes it is! It seems to load the GMC time instead of my own time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, here you need to change 'Asia/Kolkata' as per you need zone.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date_value = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface');
$today = $date_value->date()->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
$dateTimeAsTimeZone = $date_value->date(new \DateTime($today))->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
echo $dateTimeAsTimeZone = $date_value->date(new \DateTime($today))->format('H:i');
```

for one more

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
$timefc = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface');
echo $timefc->formatDateTime($this->getCreatedAt());
```

for the only current time

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
$objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
echo $date = $objDate->gmtDate('H:i');
```

Hope it works!